# Can this battery power the motors?

Tags: batteries, dc-motor

I'm trying to find a battery which can power two 24volt motors. They each use 12amps, so I think collectively they will use 24 amps. I want the battery to at least last an hour.

This battery I'm considering supposedly has 42980 mAh but I'm not sure because it says 3.7/42980mAh. Is this normal or am I being mislead into thinking it has 42980mAh when outputting 24volts. If you need more information, it can be found at the listing [https://www.amazon.com/TalentCell-PB240B1-Rechargeable-Batteries-Smartphone/dp/B07SWBS55F/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SWBS55F).

[image]

If it can provide 42980mAh it should provide more than hour because:

Approximate Running Time(h)=Battery Capacity(mAh) / Operating Current(mA)

=42980/24000 = 1.79; So it should provide roughly 1 hour 48 minutes

The main two things I am concerned is if two 24volt motors drawing from the same 24volt battery will cause a dramatic voltage drop and if I am correct in the assumption that the battery indeed has 42980mAh.

*Here's the main question: Am I right in the assumption that this battery can power both motors?*

As you can probably tell I'm new to electronics and any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm not sure if it's helpful but here are the motor stats:

[image]

Comment: Not even close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line in the "About this item" section says "output: 24V (29.4V-21V. Same Voltage Compare to 24V Lead Acid Battery) /5A Max.", so it is not suitable - it can't deliver enough current for one motor.

From the specs, I suspect that the 42980 mAH is at 3.6 volts, so the capacity would only be about 6400 mAH at 24 volts.

Comment: Thanks for the help, as for my other question if I used a 24v battery which was able to properly supply the amps would two 24v motors drawing from the same 24v battery cause a dramatic loss in voltage?

Comment: Your motor requires 206.4 amps at startup so 2 of them would need 413.2 amps which is    considerably more than the running current of 24.2 amps. This impacts both the capability of the battery to supply this current and the capacity of the connecting cable to carry this current without excessive voltage drop. I think you need to proceed with care with this project and I suggest you get some on-site help.